# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:" error while expanding hibernate console configuration in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am beginner to hibernate frame works, i want to use hibernate tools to reverse engineering , mapping and so on. But i am getting the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /ojdbc7.jar
```

While expanding the console configuration in eclipse luna. But, I am able to do for mysql database just change the jar file.

So, what I have to do to rectify this problem ?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it would be better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic here. From the guidelines: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.**"